# GoLang embedded struct class hierarchy

Tags: go

I was reading this blogpost http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/golang-embedding.html and came across these lines

> There is an important distinction to observe here. If myParent is an instance of Parent the value myParent cannot act as a Valueable. You must use the the value &myParent, a pointer to the instance, to act as a Valueable. This is because the method Value receives a *Parent not a Parent.

I have created a sample https://play.golang.org/p/ojTKZfx97g . So the questions is why calling the method **myparent.Value()** works by itself but does not work when called through interface

Answer (score 1):

Your `callValueable(v Valueable)` function has a parameter of type `Valueable` which is an interface:

```
type Valueable interface {
    Value() int64
}
```

You can pass any value to it which *implements* this interface. Your `Parent` type does not, because even though it has a `Value()` method, that method has a pointer receiver:

```
func (i *Parent) Value() int64{
    return i.value
}
```

And according to the Go Language Specification ([Method sets](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) and [Interface types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)) the method set of `Parent` does not include this method, only the method set of `*Parent`. Quoting from the Spec:

> ...The method set of any other type `T` consists of all methods declared with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).

So the type `Parent` does not implement the `Valueable` interface but the type `*Parent` does implement it.

So you can pass a `*Parent` (a **pointer** to `Parent`) as a `Valuable` value to your method, because that implements the interface. You can easily obtain a pointer by using the address `&` operator:

```
fmt.Println(callValueable(&myparent)) // This WORKS
```

Comment: Thanks icza. I think the crux of the issue for me is why golang does not automatically insert & for the case of interface whereas it does it when calling it __myparent.value()__.  Due to space constraint on comments I am adding further information on another answer

Answer (score 1):

As per **Effective Go** if the value is addressable then go will automatically insert & when calling pointer receiver method.

I did further research on this and looks like my understanding what is **addressable** is wrong. I was thinking along the line of c++ whereas as long it is lvalue then it is addressable. But it seem that in golang not everything is addressable such as

- concrete value stored in an interface is not addressable
- map element is not addressable

The interesting question then is why concrete type of interface is not addressable so that golang can automatically do &. I found this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/-ZoCu5m0kJ4. I am quoting the answer by Steven Blenkinsop which you can find at the end

> On one level, it's because the language spec says so. But ultimately, yes, it's because of a limitation on getting a pointer to pass as the receiver. You can't take the address of the value inside an interface, since its type could change (you could assign a differently typed value to the interface), among other reasons. So, if you need a pointer receiver, the pointer itself needs to be in the interface.

So the way I see for interface or map since the underlying memory address might change maybe by another thread that is why go does not automatically insert & for us as it cannot guarantee the memory address will be valid throughout the function call life cycle.